# Pass SSH key to Jenkins inbound agent container

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, containers, ssh-keys

We have our Jenkins controller setup to only run jobs in agent containers. We are using the jenkins/inbound-agent image to create containers that jobs will run in.

For our legacy non-containerized tomcat apps: we need to run a Maven build, copy the build artifact to a target server, and restart the tomcat service on that server. This requires the agent container being able to ssh to the target server to run commands, so I need to be able to provide a valid ssh key and ssh config to the agent container. (The maven build step is running successfully in the container but am unable to do the deploy steps from the container).

I tried configuring the inbound-agent image to mount a valid ssh key and ssh config
in the jenkins user's .ssh dir when it creates a container, however mounting by default gives the root user ownership of the mounted files and so was unable to ssh because of bad permissions on those files (the inbound-agent image does not have sudo installed so can't override the ownership of those files in the container as a pre-build step).

Our company's security policy mandates that we cannot bake private keys into images, so I cannot build a custom image off the base jenkins/inbound-agent image that includes the ssh key.

What is the correct way to provide an ssh key and config to the agent container so that it can interact with servers in our datacenter via ssh as part of our deployment? I believe I could create a Jenkins SSH key credential and write it into /home/jenkins/.ssh, though that would likely have to be defined as an initial step in every single job, hoping there's a better way to do this as a default step during container startup.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the specific error are you getting due to the permissions. `ssh` has different criteria for different files and it'd be helpful to know exactly what it's complaining about. It would also be helpful to run "ls -la" in the .ssh directory and include that output.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [ssh-agent-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/#plugin-content-jenkinsfile)?

store ssh key in jenkins credentials and use it like:

```
steps {
    sshagent(credentials: ['ssh-credentials-id']) {
      sh '''
          [ -d ~/.ssh ] || mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
          ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          ssh user@example.com ...
      '''
    }
}
```

or withCredentials

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "key-id", keyFileVariable: 'sshkeyfile')]) {
  sh 'ssh -i ${sshkeyfile} YOUR COMMAND'
}
```